# Facebook Analytics In-app notifications not showing push opens

Tags: android, facebook-analytics

I have implemented push in my Android app. I can send a notification from the web console and receive an in-app notification successfully. If I go to the web console Activity>Event debugging, I can see a "Push Notification Opened" event recorded, with the corresponding campaign ID.

However, if I go to Push Campaigns>In-app notifications and select the relevant campaign

- Push opens is always zero.
- Status is always "Sending"

Is there something I need to implement to get the in-app push opens recorded?

**EDIT**
The relevant Push Notification Open events are visible under Activity>Events. Just not under the Push Campaigns view.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call Facebook Event logger in intent opened when notification is opened?

```
Intent startingIntent = getIntent();
Bundle pushData = startingIntent.getBundleExtra("push");

final AppEventsLogger logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(context);
logger.logPushNotificationOpen(pushData, startingIntent.getAction());
```

Comment: I do have that in my Activity, but I think that's for push notifications rather than in-app notifications -  pushData is null. It looks like the push open event is logged within the SDK when the in-app card is presented, but not shown in the web console analytics.